# Best Approach to filter out data from array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ramda.js

I want to filter out data from an array based on certain condition.

Check if both 'isChecked' & 'isPrimaryKey' is true and if 'rename' is not empty then in the output array need to show rename otherwise show name.

The below code working perfectly for me. I want to know is there any better approach.

Also want to know is there any fault in this approach (using map for iterating over limited number of object)

```
let columnList = [
  { id:1, name: "Id", rename: "", isChecked: true, isPrimaryKey: true },
  { id:2, name: "Name", isChecked: false, isPrimaryKey: true },
  { id:3, name: "age",  rename: "Age", isChecked: true, isPrimaryKey: true },
  { id:4, name: "Designation", isChecked: true, isPrimaryKey: false },
  { id:5, name: "Salary", isChecked: false, isPrimaryKey: true },
  { id:6, name: "Department", isChecked: true, isPrimaryKey: false },
  { id:7, name: "Project", isChecked: false, isPrimaryKey: false }
];

let data = columnList.map(d => {
  if(d.isChecked && d.isPrimaryKey) {
    return (d.rename && d.rename !== '') ? d.rename : d.name;
  }
});

data = data.filter(item => item);
console.log(data);
```

> Output: ["Id", "Age"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `array.reduce` instead of `array.map` + `array.filter`.

- [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) - This function will return an array of n element with returned value. It can return partial/processed value.
- [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) - This function is used to filter items in array. This will return n elements that match the case but will not change/process them.
- [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) - This function is meant to reduce the number of items in array. In doing this, you can manipulate items and return a custom value.

Also for the case where you need to check if `rename` is available then return it else return `name`, you can achieve it using `.push(d.rename || d.name)`

```js
let columnList = [
  { id:1, name: "Id", rename: "", isChecked: true, isPrimaryKey: true },
  { id:2, name: "Name", isChecked: false, isPrimaryKey: true },
  { id:3, name: "age",  rename: "Age", isChecked: true, isPrimaryKey: true },
  { id:4, name: "Designation", isChecked: true, isPrimaryKey: false },
  { id:5, name: "Salary", isChecked: false, isPrimaryKey: true },
  { id:6, name: "Department", isChecked: true, isPrimaryKey: false },
  { id:7, name: "Project", isChecked: false, isPrimaryKey: false }
];

let data = columnList.reduce((p, d) => {
  if(d.isChecked && d.isPrimaryKey) {
    p.push(d.rename || d.name);
  }
  return p;
}, []);
console.log(data)
```

But if you still wish to go for `Array.map` + `array.filter`, you can try something like this:

```js
let columnList = [
  { id:1, name: "Id", rename: "", isChecked: true, isPrimaryKey: true },
  { id:2, name: "Name", isChecked: false, isPrimaryKey: true },
  { id:3, name: "age",  rename: "Age", isChecked: true, isPrimaryKey: true },
  { id:4, name: "Designation", isChecked: true, isPrimaryKey: false },
  { id:5, name: "Salary", isChecked: false, isPrimaryKey: true },
  { id:6, name: "Department", isChecked: true, isPrimaryKey: false },
  { id:7, name: "Project", isChecked: false, isPrimaryKey: false }
];

let data = columnList
  .filter(d => d.isChecked && d.isPrimaryKey)
  .map(d => d.rename || d.name);

console.log(data)
```

The difference is in reading. When you read it, you read it as,

> You are filtering list by `isChecked` and `isPrimaryKey` and the from the filtered, you are returning either `rename` or `name`

These functions are part of functional programming and their beauty comes when they improve readability of code. In your code, reader will have to read the logic to understand what you are trying to achieve, which beats the purpose.

Comment: Thank you. From your opinion performance wise which one is good Array.map + array.filter or Array.reduce or any another approach like ramda?

Comment: `Array.reduce` will take `O(n)` and `Array.map + Array.filter` will take `O(n + m)` where `m` represents the filtered list. So you are adding `m` iterations extra. But if you are looking for performance, nothing beats `for`. These functions improve readability at the cost of performance. But usually there is standard optimizations applied by bundler. So you should not bother much about it

Comment: Good, Thank you very much

Comment: If you have like 100-1000 items in an array, it just does not matter (performance wise), go for the readability. You can measure this and see for yourself.

Comment: Adding to @marinbgd point, the difference would be somewhere around 100ms if you have an array of around 100,000 or 1M entries. But if you are using a bundler like `webpack` etc, these functions are replaces with optimized code. So yes, you should go for readability, unless you have a trader blotter system than needs to be updated every second

Answer (score 2):

A follow-up to Rajesh's answer: if you want the clean code of `filter`-then-`map`, but don't want to add extra iterations, Ramda offers support for [transducers](https://medium.com/@roman01la/understanding-transducers-in-javascript-3500d3bd9624) in many of its list-handling functions, including [`map`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#map) and [`filter`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#filter).  The following version will iterate the list once, checking on each step if the item matches the filter, and if it does choosing the correct property via the function passed to `map`.

But the code is still nicely factored into the filtering step and then the mapping step.

```js
let columnList = [
  { id:1, name: "Id", rename: "", isChecked: true, isPrimaryKey: true },
  { id:2, name: "Name", isChecked: false, isPrimaryKey: true },
  { id:3, name: "age",  rename: "Age", isChecked: true, isPrimaryKey: true },
  { id:4, name: "Designation", isChecked: true, isPrimaryKey: false },
  { id:5, name: "Salary", isChecked: false, isPrimaryKey: true },
  { id:6, name: "Department", isChecked: true, isPrimaryKey: false },
  { id:7, name: "Project", isChecked: false, isPrimaryKey: false }
];


const getCols = R.into([], R.compose(
  R.filter(d => d.isChecked && d.isPrimaryKey),
  R.map(d => d.rename || d.name)
))

const cols = getCols(columnList)

console.log(cols)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

You also asked if there was an issue with your approach.  There might be.  As well as the extra iterations already discussed, there are two more concerns: First, using `filter` with `item => item` will disallow not just the `null`/`undefined` values but also any false-y value, most notably `0`.  So if you were trying to extract a list in which `0` might be a reasonable value, this will exclude it.  Second, in functional programming, it's generally considered a bad habit to reassign variables.  So `data = data.filter(...)` is much frowned-upon.